# How do you add a <div> around the second level of a Menu?

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I've been searching around online and reading up on walkers but I can't figure out how to do this.

Basically I need a `<div class="sub-container">` wrapped around the second level of the menu but not the first level, third level or any of its children (obviously, it will technically be wrapped around the third level and its children because they are inside the second level, but I don't want it directly wrapped around them).

I found a method that put the `<div>` around the second level and then all of its children and tried tweaking it, but I just get a bunch of errors. I found it here: http://webdevelopmentspider.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/how-to-wrap-wordpress-sub-menu-with-div.html

Comment: Post your tweaked coded.

Comment: I didn't work, so I got rid of it and went back to the original code from the website above so that I can style other elements without a bunch of errors in the way.